# Customise decimal point for Piechart donut

Tags: label, rounding, pie-chart

This is my first ever PiecDonut chart, the percentage as the label looks too messy. I wants it to be 1 or 2 decimal point i.e. Beef (78.97%). Any suggestion please? Thanks in advance.

[image: GHG emissions by gas type]

Here is my code and [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ffvxuqffhhimo6q/dat.donut.xlsx?dl=0).

```
dat <- read_excel('dat.donut.xlsx' , "GHG", range = "A1:I4") %>% 
gather("System", "GHG", -c(Type)) %>% 
  filter(!GHG=="0")

p <- PieDonut(dat, aes(Type, System, count=GHG), title = "GHG Emissions Profile by Gas Type",
              #start=3*pi/2,
              labelpositionThreshold=0.1,
               ratioByGroup = FALSE, 
               explode = 1,
              explodePie = TRUE,
              explodeDonut = FALSE,
              maxx=1.7,
              donutLabelSize = 4,
              pieLabelSize = 5,
              titlesize = 8,
              labelposition = getOption("PieDonut.labelposition", 1),
              family = getOption("PieDonut.family", ""),
              showRatioThreshold = getOption("PieDonut.showRatioThreshold", 0.02),
              explodePos = 0.1)
```